# Pygame. How Do I Resize My Fish Player Image Everytime It Eats A Fish?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to make my fish bigger everytime it eats a fish but I am not sure why its not working this is what I did

everything else works but my playerman height or width is not adding up
[video](https://gyazo.com/282aabce7c7bfd2f429d46c09ffc914d)

```
# our main loop
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False

         #[...........]
    for blac in blacs:
        if playerman.rect.colliderect(blac.rect):
            playerman.width += 10
            playerman.height += 10
            blac.x = 880
```

my full code:
https://pastebin.com/iL5h4fst

Comment: `playerman` is an instance of class `player` (you should capitalize that `Player` for proper Python PEP-8 style). When you modify `playerman.width += 10` and `.height`, it's better style to create a method `resize(new_width, new_height)`, rather than reach inside an instance's member variables as you do. Can you refactor like that, rerun it and tell us if this still happens? (might as well throw in a verbose flag `resize(new_width, new_height, verbose=True)` and have it print out its args when it gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to scale all the images of the player with [`pygame.transform.smoothscale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale), when the size is inreased:

```py
if playerman.rect.colliderect(blac.rect):
    playerman.width += 10
    playerman.height += 10
    blac.x = 880
    playerman.right = [pygame.transform.scale(image, (playerman.width,playerman.height)) for image in playerman.right]
    playerman.left = [pygame.transform.scale(image, (playerman.width,playerman.height)) for image in playerman.left]
    playerman.rect = pygame.Rect(playerman.x, playerman.y, playerman.width, playerman.height)
```

The attributes `self.width` and `self.height` have to be initialized by the down scaled size of the images (`image.get_width()//8` respectively `image.get_height()//8`)

As the player grows, you'll need to multiply the size of the player by a scale factor to keep the aspect ratio. When using `pygame.transform.scale`, round the width and height to integral numbers:

```py
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        # [...]

        self.right_original = [pygame.image.load("r" + str(i) + ".png") for i in range(1, 13)]
        self.left_original = [pygame.image.load("l" + str(i) + ".png") for i in range(1, 13)]
        self.width = self.right_original[0].get_width() / 8
        self.height = self.right_original[0].get_height() / 8
        self.scale_images()

        # [...]

    def scale_images(self):
        w, h = round(self.width), round(self.height)
        self.right = [pygame.transform.scale(image, (w, h)) for image in self.right_original]
        self.left = [pygame.transform.scale(image, (w, h)) for image in self.left_original]
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, w, h)

    def collide(self, other_rect):
        return self.rect.colliderect(other_rect)

    def grow(self, scale):
        self.width *= scale
        self.height *= scale
        self.scale_images()
```

```py
for blac in blacs:
    if playerman.collide(blac):
        blac.x = 880
        playerman.grow(1.1)
```

Comment: its good but https://gyazo.com/29bc7258e91aa195244aa2e1f3f173aa pixels my sprite way to much

Comment: @HabibIsmail Try to scale the original images, rather than scaling scaled images.  See the 2nd part of the answer.

Comment: could I ask one more thing sorry if I am troubling you but I am not sure why my width is alawys more then my height https://gyazo.com/5f4baca6cbefee0b87ce54947b7c8fb6?token=9117ee0fd2f45620183aa0dcf68a675a also is there a way I could make my fish width and height grow slower because if I put 1 it still grows the same rate as 10 it grows way to fast

Comment: @HabibIsmail `self.width` and `self.height` have to be initialized by `image.get_width()//8` respectively `image.get_height()//8`

Comment: @HabibIsmail I've improved the answer.

Comment: do you know why I am getting an error name 'right_original' is not defined but its defined already in the class

Comment: @HabibIsmail My bad. `right_original` is not specified, but `self.right_original` is specified.